# keycloak session is not terminated after successfully logout

Tags: angularjs, angular, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I am using `keycloak.logout()` to logout from my angular4 and angularjs app. i can logout successfully, but after logout when I go to keycloak server, I am getting my session active. how to resolve that issue?

Comment: logout  successful means you redirect to login page?

Comment: yes. first I hit kc.logout(). After that, the login page opens again. but the session is still there.

Comment: are you using two different browsers (or one plus an incognito session) to log to keyclock and you angular app? Otherwise sharing the same session over different tabs on the same browser could not work

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is a number of years old at this point but as someone who recently ran into this problem and managed to fix it I thought I owed it to give a response.

In my case the issue was caused from calling the `keycloak.logout()` function on a `(click)` event for an **anchor** tag. By changing the function call to be triggered by a **button** the session seemed to correctly close and redirect to the login page.

More specifically given some component with a `logOut()` function:

```
logout.component.ts

async logOut() {
  await this._keycloak.logout(window.location.origin)
}
```

Using:

```html
logout.component.html

<a href="..." (click)="logOut()"> Log Out </a>
```

Would cause the session not to be closed, but by replacing `<a>` with `<button>` the issue was resolved.

```html
signout.component.html

<button (click)="logOut()" clrDropdownItem>Log out</button>
```